# How to delete all but the most recent files in a directory of folders and files

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that has a bunch of backups in in separated by folder. I want a script to use the directory (C:\Users\user\Desktop\TEST) and in that directory I have any number of folders with any number of files in them, I only want to keep the latest in the folder for every folder in the directory and delete the rest.

I have this but it only does 1 folder at a time and it has to be hardcoded.

```
$path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TEST\Folder1"
$FileNumber = (get-childitem $path).count - 1
get-childitem -path $path | sort CreationTime -Descending | select -last $FileNumber |  Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

Is there any way to automate this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$Path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TEST"
$Folders = Get-ChildItem $Path
foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    $FolderName = $Folder.FullName
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderName
    $FileNumber = $Files.Count - 1
    $Files | sort CreationTime -Descending | select -last $FileNumber | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a loop of your choice to accomplish this, this example uses [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2). Instead of using [`Select-Object -Last N`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-3-select-processes-using-the-most-memory) you could just use [`Select-Object -Skip 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-7-select-all-but-the-first-object) to skip the newest file. Also note the use of `-Directory` and `-File` with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) to filter only directories or only files.

```
$path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TEST\Folder1"

# Get all Directories in `$path`
Get-ChildItem $path -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    # For each Directory, get the Files
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File |
        # Sort them from Newest to Oldest
        Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending |
        # Skip the first 1 (the newest)
        Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        # Remove the rest
        Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
}
```